# Google Colab: How to read all available file names from google drive

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

We are appending data in bigquery table from all the CSV files available on google drive.
below is the code which is working fine for a single file (trainers.csv).

Need help in running all the files in a single go. How can i read all the available CSV files from google drive & save it to pandas dataframe & run my complete process in loop?

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')

my_data = pd.read_csv('/content/drive/MyDrive/Vestiaire_data/july-2022/trainers.csv',encoding = 'ISO-8859-1',low_memory=False)

my_data.to_gbq(-------------)
```

Comment: You can get all the file names in a list and iterate over them in a loop. Please refer to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20906474/import-multiple-csv-files-into-pandas-and-concatenate-into-one-dataframe

Answer (score 3):

It is easy. Just get all the files from the directory using **OS** module and iterate all the **CSV** files and append all in one dataframe like this.

```
import pandas as pd
import os

directory_path = '/content/drive/MyDrive/Vestiaire_data/july-2022'
directory_files = os.listdir(directory_path)

df = pd.Dataframe()
for file in directory_files:
    df_file = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(directory_path, file), encoding = 'ISO-8859-1',low_memory=False)
    df = pd.concat([df, df_file])

# Then save the df here
```

Just make sure that all the CSV's have the same structure